# Using legacy CodeIgniter project inside Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, laravel-8, codeigniter-3

I have a legacy project built on codeigniter 3 and we're looking to upgrade to the latest Laravel version. From some of the answers here, I can infer that it is definitely possible, I have multiple questions before starting.

1. Would it be practical? (would making it work with each other be a huge enough pain to completely rebuild the system on laravel)
2. Would it work across different PHP versions? (Current: 5.something; desired: 8.1)
3. If they're both running on the same domain, would session management be an issue? (would I be able to share session variables across the frameworks?)
   Thanks for reading

Comment: CodeIgniter to  Laravel. Do it. But can't reuse CI components.

Comment: this question is way to broad! please split it up into smaller pieces

Answer (score 1):

It looks like CodeIgniter uses lots of global variables.

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/common_functions.html

I'm not a Laravel dev, but I'm assuming that as a relatively modern framework, Laravel does not rely on many globals by default. So I suppose there's more *opportunity* for conflict, but only if someone is abusing Laravel.

(Laravel people: Feel free to correct me on this.)

Regarding PHP 8: CodeIgniter has at least passed this guy's smoke test on PHP 8.

https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-78091.html

Since minor versions theoretically don't contain breaking changes, you may find success on 8.1 as well.

Regarding sessions: I know nothing about how either framework handles sessions, so I can't speak to this.

As for whether it's a *good idea*: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to do. Are you going to have a CodeIgniter project running side-by-side with a Laravel project, using a separate subdomain for each? Or are you going to try to make the existing CodeIgniter project live inside of a Laravel directory structure, as the title of the question currently implies?

If the latter, I would say you're in for some tears. It sounds very painful. The former could work pretty well, I would imagine, especially if you're already using your PHP mainly to serve API endpoints and can just gradually move all the endpoints over to the new platform, one at a time.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mr. Mayor. I'm trying to create a project that routes the old paths to legacy codebase and the new ones to laravel. However, I am open to other suggestions that can make the transition easier while not impacting the client's in any way

Comment: And thanks for linking the article that shows running CI3 with PHP8 is possible. I never even thought that could work. My plan is to create a laravel repository that contains the codeigniter codebase in a folder called legacy or something. I would start translating the old routes into laravel as I work through every feature, rebuilding it into laravel.